# Ubuntu Server 20.04 Keeps Shutting Down

Tags: server, shutdown

I'm fairly new to using ubuntu and brand new to using ubuntu server. I've been working on setting up a physical home server to run some basic tasks. I had the server up and running fine for a couple of days, but then I noticed I was having issues connecting to the server via ssh and then I discovered the server was actually off. I would turn it back on, and it would be fine and then about 45 mins later it would turn off again.

I pulled some of the syslogs to see what was going on here, but I'm fairly inexperienced in this and am having trouble finding out what's going on here. Below are some of the logs before the server shut down.

```
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman ModemManager[931]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman NetworkManager[823]: <info>  [1632074508.4930] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman NetworkManager[823]: <info>  [1632074508.4931] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman gnome-shell[1512]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman logger[6267]: <13>Sep 19 18:01:48 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Succeeded.
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Succeeded.
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1269]: (**) Option "fd" "27"
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1269]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1269]: (**) Option "fd" "49"
Sep 19 18:01:48 coman /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1269]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
Sep 19 18:01:49 coman kernel: [ 2432.319507] rfkill: input handler enabled
Sep 19 18:01:49 coman gnome-shell[1512]: Error checking authorization for action id org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
Sep 19 18:01:49 coman gnome-shell[1512]: Error checking authorization for action id org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
Sep 19 18:01:49 coman /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1269]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Sep 19 18:01:49 coman /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1269]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Sep 19 18:01:49 coman systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Succeeded.
Sep 19 18:01:49 coman systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Sep 19 18:01:49 coman systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Sep 19 18:01:49 coman systemd-sleep[6297]: Suspending system...
Sep 19 18:01:49 coman kernel: [ 2432.414801] PM: suspend entry (deep)
```

This server just sits in a closet and nobody is physically touching it. It also shuts down if I turn it on and then just completely leave it alone.

Comment: Servers do not normally have a GUI, however you appear to be running some sort of graphical display manager. Servers do not turn of by themselves, but I do not know about desktop (versions with graphical display managers).

Comment: Is there a way to see what GUI is running and remove it? I would like to run the server fully from the CLI. I'm sure I installed some package that included it without realizing. I just hooked it up to a monitor and rebooted it and it did show the GUI and took me to a login screen. Ideally I would like it to not have any GUI and just boot straight to the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the exact issue was, but I went and tried to remove any program dealing with the GUI.

I then wen't and opened `/etc/defaullt/grub` and added the parameter `consoleblank=0` and saved.

I then ran `sudo update-grub` and rebooted my server. Hooked it up to a monitor and it no longer boots to any GUI and the server has been online now for over 24 hours straight with no random shutdowns.

I think what was happening was it was booting to a GUI login screen and since no one was logging directly into the server it would try to go into sleep mode. This server is built with older computer parts where I did have issues with this old PC waking up from sleep mode. This hardware is probably at fault for the issue but I've seemed to at least fix it for now with the above process.